# ListFieldIterator does not create two column Table

Tags: 2013, list-form

I created a WebPart (SharePoint 2013) which contains a ListFieldIterator to display the fields of a list like the New-/EditForm does. According to all online examples and the default new/edit form of a list, the fields should be aligned in a two column table.

```
fieldname    input
fieldname2   input2
...
```

But in my case no table is created and all content is displayed one after another

```
fieldname
input
fieldname2
input2
...
```

I haven't done anything fancy, just the default values. The ListId is set in the codebehind after the OnInit Event. The ASCX File Snippet:

```
<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="ListFieldIterator1" runat="server" ControlMode="New"></SharePoint:ListFieldIterator>
```

What do I have to do to get the two column view (or what have I done wrong, that I did not get it)?

**Update**: Here is the HTML code created by the Iterator. The two br's are from my code just before the Iterator. Now I see it does create *tr* and *tds* but no *table* tag..?? (this may be the reason why the IE Developer Tool stripped them all out and I thought there are no row and cell tags). So my (new) question: Why is there no Table tag?

```
<br /><br />


    <tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>Headline<span class="ms-accentText" title="This is a required field." > *</span></nobr>
</h3></td>
    <td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">
    <!-- FieldName="Headline"
         FieldInternalName="Title"
         FieldType="SPFieldText"
      -->
        <span dir="none">
    <input name="ctl00$[...]$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="200" id="ctl00_[...]_TextField" title="Headline" class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" /><br />
</span>


    </td>
</tr>
... more fields ...
```

**Update**: This is the code I use now. I guess it is really intended that the ListFieldIterator does not create table tags in case you want to add custom fields to the same table. Until someone has a better Explanation?

```
<table class="ms-formtable">
    <SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="ListFieldIterator1" runat="server" ControlMode="New"></SharePoint:ListFieldIterator>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please provide html markup that was rendered for field controls?

Comment: Updated the post. Seems like the ListFieldIterator does not create the <table> Tag. I will try adding it manually but this is a big hack and can't be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I did not find any other Solutions to this problem, I guess that adding your own `table` tag is the only solution to this *Feature*. Maybe so you can concatenate serveral ListFieldIterators to one large table.

```
<table class="ms-formtable">
  <SharePoint:ListFieldIterator ID="ListFieldIterator1" runat="server" ControlMode="New"></SharePoint:ListFieldIterator>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides surrounding the iterator with a table you must instruct the iterator control to apply a specific rendering template: **PropertyIterator** (in my case). When using this template it will generate the field controls and labels inside table cells, using a row per field

```
<table class="ms-formtable" border="0" cellpadding="2">
<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator runat="server" ID="**FormIterator**" TemplateName="PropertyIterator" />
</table>
```